# Get the latest directory (not the latest file)

Tags: shell, files, ls, timestamps

My folder `parent` has the following content:

```
A.Folder B.Folder C.File
```

It has both folders and files inside. `B.Folder` is newer. Now I just want to get `B.Folder`, how could I achieve this? I tried this,

```
ls -ltr ./parent | grep '^d' | tail -1
```

but it gives me `drwxrwxr-x 2 user user   4096 Jun 13 10:53 B.Folder`, but I just need the name `B.Folder`.

Comment: use this `ls -ltr ./parent | grep '^d' | tail -1| awk '{print $NF}'`

Comment: Using awk works, but I want to see if there is a cleaner solution. :)

Comment: find . -maxdepth 1 -type d | TZ=utc xargs ls -ld --full-time | sort -k 6

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try this:

```
$ ls -td -- */ | head -n 1
```

`-t` options make `ls` sort by modification time, newest first.

If you want remove `/`:

```
$ ls -td -- */ | head -n 1 | cut -d'/' -f1
```

Comment: How to get rid of slash `/`?

Comment: This does not work if you are in another folder. I mean `ls -td -- ./parent | head -n 1` does not give me the correct results, do I HAVE TO use subshell such as `cd ./parent` every time and execute this command? Any solution?

Comment: @Daniel: You must run my answer in current working directory to make it works. Otherwise, you must use a relative path like Herson's answer.

Comment: Removing last / doesn't work. Example:
/home/cuo/bin/

Expected: /home/cuo/bin

Comment: How we get the time details with above command?

Answer (score 7):

```
ls -td -- ./parent/*/ | head -n1 | cut -d'/' -f2
```

Difference to [Herson's solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136993) is the slash after `*`, which makes the shell ignore all non-dir files.
Difference to [Gnouc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/136978), it'll work if you are in another folder.

Cut needs to know the number of parent directories (2) in order to delete trailing '/'. If you don't have that, use

```
VAR=$(ls -dt -- parent/*/ | head -n1); echo "${VAR::-1}"
```

Comment: the `/*/` causes ls to not find the dir with `No such file or directory` fr an empty directory it seems

Answer (score 5):

Obligatory zsh answer:

```
latest_directory=(parent/*(/om[1]))
```

The characters in parentheses are [glob qualifiers](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers): `/` to match only directories, `om` to sort matches by increasing age, and `[1]` to retain only the first (i.e. newest) match. Add `N` if you want to get an empty array (normally you get a 1-elementy array) if there is no subdirectory of `parent`.

Alternatively, assuming that `parent` doesn't contain any shell globbing character:

```
latest_directory='parent/*(/om[1])'; latest_directory=$~latest_directory
```

If you don't have zsh but you have recent GNU tools (i.e. non-embedded Linux or Cygwin), you can use `find`, but it's cumbersome. Here's one way:

```
latest_directory_inode=$(find parent -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d -printf '%Ts %i\n' | sort -n | sed -n '1 s/.* //p')
latest_directory=$(find parent -maxdepth 1 -inum "$latest_directory_inode")
```

There's a simple solution with `ls`, which works as long as no directory name contains newlines or (on some systems) non-printable characters:

```
latest_directory=$(ls -td parent/*/ | head -n1)
latest_directory=${latest_directory%/}
```

Comment: It works without `/`, because everything is a file maybe. So it is `latest_directory=(parent/*(om[1]))` where `o` is most recent and `m` modification date. Probably in a huuuge directory, adding `/` is fast to skip files.

Comment: @Timo `parent/*(om[1])` doesn't work: it gives you the latest file, whether it's a directory or not. The question here was to get the latest directory, skipping files that are not directories.

Answer (score 3):

You can do:

```
ls -td -- ../parent/* | head -n 1
```

Comment: This gives the latest file. Daniel only wants directories.

Answer (score 3):

Following command will do the job even in case of directory name containing space :

```
cp `find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d  -exec stat --printf="%Y\t%n\n" {} \;  |sort -n -r |head -1 |cut -f2'`/* /target-directory/.
```

The updated explanation of the stuff in the backticks is:

- `.` - the current directory (you may want to specify an absolute path here)
- `-mindepth/-maxdepth` - restrict the find command only to the immediate children of the current directory
- `-type d` - only directories
- `-exec stat ..` - outputs the modified time and the  name of the directory from find separated with a tab (and not a space)
- `sort -n -r |head -1 | cut -f2` - date orders the directory and outputs the entire name of the most recently modified (even if containing some space as cut default delimiter tab)